# Error Running React Native Skia in Solito Repo: Can't Resolve 'react-native-reanimated/package.json

Tags: react-native, web, expo, next.js13, monorepo

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run `React Native Skia` in the `Solito` repository for both mobile and web. Mobile seems to work fine, but I'm running into a problem on the web platform, which is also causing issues during the `Next.js` build. I hope someone can provide some guidance on resolving this issue.

> warn ../../node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/lib/module/external/reanimated/moduleWrapper.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated/package.json' in '/Users/apple/Documents/chessingly-frontend/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/lib/module/external/reanimated'

Expecting result for above problem is to run `@shopify/react-native-skia` on web without having any issues. If I run it on development environment then it works fine but while creating `Next.js` build for deploying it on docker then it gives above error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.